# ¿Mejor practica para realizar varias peticiones ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Necesito despejar la siguiente duda. Quiero realizar 2 peticiones ajax, el problema esta en que yo realizo la peticion 1 (obtengo un dato) y necesito pasar ese dato a la peticion 2. He realizado lo siguiente:

1. Creo un ajax (jquery) y obtengo el dato
2. Dentro de este ajax creo el siguiente para enviar el dato obtenido a la siguiente direccion

**ERROR** Haciendolo de esta manera, obtengo error de cors. Si yo hago el ajax por fuera no puedo obtener el dato de la peticion 1

**POSIBLE SOLUCION** Al obtener el dato de la peticion 1, guardarlo en un input oculto para luego tomarlo y hacer la segunda peticion

**NOTA** Pienso que deberia existir otra manera mas practica y mas profesional para realizar esta tarea, alguna sugerencia?

**CODIGO - Si con fetch u otra libreria es mejor practica, favor notificar**

```
    $.getJSON("endpoint1", function (data) {
        var datos = data;
        $.ajax(
            {
                url: "endpoint2",
                data: { datos: datos },
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (cb) {
                    console.log('success')
                }
            })
    })
```

Comment: Deberias agregar tu codigo.

Comment: Podrías agregar el fragmento de código de como invocas el segundo AJAX?

Comment: actualizado, favor revisar y quitar el negativo @alanfcm

Comment: actualizado, favor revisar y quitar el negativo @JocksanCruz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax ofrece la posibilidad de utilizar callbacks al realizar una solicitud, ejemplo:

```
function getUserLocation(callback) {
  $.ajax('https://www.example.com/location.json', callback)
}

function getCurrentWeather(userLocation, callback) {
  $.ajax('https://www.example.com/weather' + userLocation +  '.json', callback);
}

getUserLocation(function(user) {
   getCurrentWeather(user, function(weather) {
       console.log("Got weather", weather); 
   });
});
```

*Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36820347/8067370*

Aquí básicamente lo que sucede es lo siguiente: creamos dos funciones, la primera `getUserLocation` es la encargada de traernos el dato que nos haga falta, en el ejemplo simplemente trae la ubicación del usuario. La segunda función, `getCurrentWeather` toma esa ubicación como parametro y realiza la segunda petición. Al final una vez ambas peticiones se hayan realizado, se lanzará el ultimo callback, en el ejemplo, se imprimirá en consola `Got weather`.

Saludos!

Comment: correto, gracias!